How to know which kth order of second order filter to be used in series for microphone signal equalisation?
In my audio dsp design, I have used number of taps = 12 . However the second order filter are used in series as follows:
SOF9th order -> SOF 11th order -> SOF10th order -> SOF 8th order -> ....
I want to know how is this design made and based on what factors the "kth order" are designed in series ?

Filters are commutative. Order doesn't matter as a first order effect. However order can affect noise performance especially in fixed point applications (but in floating point as well)

So , what if I design the SOFxth order like below : 1st order -> 6th order -> 8th order -> 9th order -> 10th order -> 11th order -> 12th order ?? How will affect the floating point applications (half duplex communication) and noise performance?
